# How to close a soap client while making async calls?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, soap

I am calling a soap service asynchronously but stuck at a point where I need to close a soap client connection. Not much help from previous post either: [How to close Client Proxy with Async Call WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588549/how-to-close-client-proxy-with-async-call-wcf)

Below is my code so far.

Method below (GetFieldList(....) calls generic method ApiClient.GetResponse(....) with request parameters and what service to invoke

```
 public async Task<ServiceReference.GetFieldListResponse> GetFieldList(string identifier)
    {
        var request = new GetFieldListRequest
        {
            Header = new Header {Username = ApiSettings.Instance.ApiToken},
            AGroup = "",
            IdType = "",
            Id = ""
        };
        var response = await ApiClient.GetResponse(request, (c) => c.GetFieldListAsync(request.Header, request.Id, request.IdType, request.AGroup));
        return response;
    }
```

In the method below, I have commented out finally block because the connection was being closed before a response was returned to the calling method.

```
 public class ApiClient
 {

    public static TResponse GetResponse<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request, 
            Func<SoapClient, TResponse> handler,
            string apiMethodName = "")
    where TResponse : class
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling: " + typeof(TRequest).Name);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiMethodName))
        {
            apiMethodName = typeof(TRequest).Name.Replace("Request", string.Empty);
        }

       // creates a soap connection
        var client = WebServiceClient.CreateServiceInstance();
        TResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            //webservice call is invoked here
            response = handler(client);
        }
        catch (FaultException exception)
        {
            throw new ApiException(string.Format("Api error on {0}.", apiMethodName), exception);
        }

         //if this finally block is not commented, connection is closed before a response was returned to the calling method.
        //finally
        //{
        //  client.Close();
        //}

        return response;
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old post and you have probably figured it out what was wrong with it but just out of curiosity , how are you able to await GetResponse when there is no async on it and also was the problem with you not "await"ing "GetFieldListAsync"  due to which it exited your scope and the connection got killed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a global WebServiceClient or ApiClient, and do GetResponse and CloseClient in two threads. That way, even you are waiting for response, you can force trigger client close in CloseClient thread.